# VB.NET The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden A FILE DOWNLOAD APP

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a file download app using vb.net but when i debug the app and press the button i see this error. How can i solve this problem ?

MY CODE :

[image]

ERROR :

[image]

Comment: Guessing by the 403 error, you need to authenticate with the file sever in some way.  Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: In future please add your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like thinkbroadband's server doesn't like serving that file to things it considers bots/not real browsers. You'll have to mimic a real browser instead:

```
        Dim x As New WebClient
        x.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.45")
        x.DownloadFile("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip", "c:\temp\a.zip")
```

How did I know this? I opened my browser developer tools (F12), downloaded the file OK in the browser and looked at what headers were sent for an OK result, then pared it down to just the important one (useragent)