# Is it possible to use Browser control or E2 to download files without "Access Denied" error

Tags: vb.net, download, webclient

I am trying to grab some PDFs and other files from a subscription web site (I have a paid subscription) where the current process of downloading is a tedious right click, "Save As"...

I have a list of all of the URLs to each file I want, and if I copy and paste these URLs DIRECTLY into a browser, I have access to the file, and can successfully "Save As".

However, if I try to download the files directly using code, I get an Access Denied error, I assume because whatever security is placed on the site based on my login, that info is not being accessed unless I'm using the browser directly. Origin, etc.

My goal is naturally to be able to just loop through my list of URLs...

So, is there a way to somehow figure out how to pass my "login" info so that I can access the files directly? Or a different way to download?

I've been trying to use VB.Net WebClient for the download -

wc.DownloadFile(sFile, sDest)

It works fine for non "protected" files.

Wondering if I can have better luck using ASP.Net...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[VB.NET The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden A FILE DOWNLOAD APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620299/vb-net-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-a-file-download-app)

Found the answer here.

Dim x As New WebClient

x.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.45")

x.DownloadFile(sWebFile, sDestLocalFile)

Thanks